# Passing PHP array through CURL PUT generates notice undefined index

Tags: php, rest, curl, put

I am working on a basic REST application in PHP and I have the following code.
Client side code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($ch ,  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "http://localhost/Hello/Rest");
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     
                  http_build_query(array("username"     => "test")));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($output);
curl_close($ch);
```

Server side code:

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
echo "This is a PUT request";
echo "<br>";
echo $username;
echo "<br>";
```

For some reason $_REQUEST['username'] is not recognized.Generates undefined index.

Not really sure what was missing that causes this error.

Comment: can you var_dump whole request ?

Comment: @ogres : I did it was empty.I think the way we are passing parameter is wrong.

Comment: can you also var_dump $_SERVER and check the request itself?

Comment: With put request shouldnt you also set Content-Length of your fields ?

Comment: As per PHP's documentation: $_REQUEST is  "An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.":http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php.  Any particular reason you are using "PUT" rather than "GET" or "POST" HTTP methods?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer and others Sorry guys if there is any confusion. I have changed the title and add a new tag REST with this question in order to clear the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @NaijaProgrammer pointed out, $_REQUEST does not contain PUT values. If you want to stick with PUT, you will need to modify your server code. See this link [for more information.](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php)

```
// for put requests
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
$username = $post_vars['username'];
echo "This is a PUT request";
echo "<br>";
echo $username;
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which resolves the issues.Cheers Mate.LUV SO.

Comment: Glad it helped. You might consider accepting it then ;-)

Answer (score -4):

you must return your $output

```
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
 curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
 curl_setopt($ch ,  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
 curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "http://localhost/Hello/Rest");
 curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     
              http_build_query(array("username"     => "test")));
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 return $output;
```

Comment: Returning the output of `curl_exec` will not help. Read the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php